# Time out exception when invoke rest webservice in android

Tags: android, web-services

I am trying to call rest web services in andoid, but i have always a time out exception.
The code is:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  

HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://XXXX:8080/YYY/zzzz?username=0001epd&password=1111");

ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();  
try {  
        String result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);  
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
           e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (IOException e) {  
          e.printStackTrace();  
           }  
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Do you have any idea where is the error?

In the manifest I added  android.permission.INTERNET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this on emulator, did you try putting the above url on emulator browser and see if you get the result. If you can see the result in browser and you are behind proxy then try adding the below lines in your code

```
HttpParams my_httpParams = new BasicHttpParams(); 

final String proxyHost = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultHost();

final int proxyPort = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultPort();

if(proxyPort != -1)
{
  my_httpParams.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort));            
}
```

Pass the HttpParams in DefaultHttpClient

Comment: This solution work fine with the sim data. Thanks for the support

Comment: I am able to connect from Emulator, but if try from device I get exception - ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /10.0.0.172:80 timed out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your internet connection at your mobile device or work station is to slow or the remote service takes some time. You can test it in using your internet browser for requesting the REST url.

At least you can try to increase the timeouts in your code:

```
final int timeout = 10000; //ms
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeout);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeout);
final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it's the kind of timeout you can fix by just upping the limit as Impression suggests, this sounds more like a networking problem with your setup to reach the server.

Is this from an emulator or a real device? Make sure you can actually reach the server (eg see what entering `XXXX:8080` in the Browser does) ; if you're on the emulator trying to connect to your local machine you need to use `10.0.2.2` as the IP address (not 127.0.0.1 or your IP on the LAN). And if you're on a physical device, the usual client-server network check rules apply:

- Are you on the same LAN/subnet as your server, if it's a local development server?
- If you're trying to make the connection externally over the Internet and not from your LAN, are you sure all the right firewall ports are opened up to make the external request from your development server?
- Is your server software set up to accept connections from external requests? (Some development servers, like Django, are set up to only accept localhost connections by default for security reasons).

Comment: Yes, it is not a problem of timeout. I set the timeout with the different value and the problem is not resolved. I am working with a real device and the same web service i am able to consume via iphone.

Comment: Moreover it is not a problem of firewall since the ip are public and I use a data sim to connect. Moreover from the browser on android phone I am able to consume it.

Comment: Can you post the traceback from Logcat for your exception?